# I am getting missing behaviour definition for the preceding method call:

Tags: junit, easymock

I am new to unit test. I am trying to create test case of a method which is calling an static method. For this static method I am getting  "getting missing behaviour definition for the preceding method call:"

Comment: Please provide code or something so people can help.

Comment: Yes. Please provide some code to get a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

EasyMock can't mock static methods. So that's probably the problem. But having actual failing code will help providing a full answer.